# ColorStateList doesn't work programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to set a `ColorStateList` of my `EditText` ***programmatically***

```
ColorStateList textColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                new int[]{},
        },
        new int[]{
                R.color.DARK_GRAY_COLOR,
                R.color.LIGHT_RED_COLOR,
                R.color.DARK_GRAY_COLOR});
```

Here is how I use it on my `EditText`

```
    editText.setTextColor(textColorStateList);
```

But whenever I set the `editText.setEnabled(false);` The color of my `editText` stays the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second parameter is the list of colors not of the id of resources. Use it like

```
new int[]{
    getColor(R.color.DARK_GRAY_COLOR),
    getColor(R.color.LIGHT_RED_COLOR),
    getColor(R.color.DARK_GRAY_COLOR) }
```